# cant connect button to uiview in xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to create my own custom keyboard for iOS 8 on XCode 6-beta 4. When I try to connect a button to my keyboard.h file, there's no connection for me to add.

Here's the keyboard.h code:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface Keyboard : UIView 

    @end
```

I would post an image of my keyboard.xib but apparently I don't have enough reputation to do that.

When I click and drag the button to keyboard.h, no connection happens when there should be one. I don't know if this is a flaw in this beta version of XCode 6 or I'm doing something wrong. I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Did you set custom class of a view in the xib to `Keyboard`?

Comment: Yes. The custom class name is QButton. I tried connecting the button to my keyboard.h file but it still won't connect. There must be a silly error I'm making

Comment: I'm talking about the root view of your `xib`, not the specific button, which is a subview of that view. Its type should be set to `Keyboard` in order to be able to drag outlets from xib to the code.

Comment: Glad that helped! Added as an answer, would you be so kind to accept it as a solution?

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow, so how would I accept it as a solution?

Comment: There's a checkmark outline under the answers' rating & up/down arrows, you can just click that checkmark to accept, AFAIK

Comment: I tried clicking the upvote button but I was told I needed 15 reputation to vote up. I only have 1 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Root view of your xib should have its class set to `Keyboard`, otherwise you won't be able to drag outlets from xib to your `Keyboard` class.